# How can I build a website without 'coding' knowledge?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, html

I have a Ubuntu server network & have decided to make a website. Can anyone suggest some free tools that will help me do this **without** having to code HTML or CSS?

Answer (score 5):

WordPress is a neat CMS for running a website. I'll give you instructions on how to install it.

You can install LAMP (Stack of Apache, PHP and MySQl) by running this terminal command on the server:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Then, after that you can install [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install wordpress
```

Then you can fire up WordPress by entering the ip address of the server in the window of a client browser. For example, if the server IP address on the LAN is 10.25.43.25, then enter 10.25.43.25 in the browser of any desktop attached to the LAN. You'll get the WordPress install page. Follow the instructions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) to install WordPress.

[Drupal](http://drupal.org/) is another popular CMS. You can install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install drupal6
```

Ubuntu has version 6 of drupal. The latest is version 7. You can install drupal 7 by following [this guide](http://drupal.org/start).

Comment: hey, Why didn't you mention Joomla, the famous Cms?..

Comment: Aneeshep: I find Joomla to be confusing for newcomers, and hence I recommended Drupal to him.

Comment: I think it depends on the user perspective. There is nothing to be confused. There are large collection of tutorials, howtos, forums, irc channel etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

On the server you will be needing Apache with php and mysql as a base. From this there are many CMS that will help you build your site. As mentioned WordPress is great for blogs as it also has apps on various mobile platforms.
My preference for building full websites is Joomla, but there is also Drupal, Concrete5, Mambo and probably many more smaller platforms. 
Whichever platform you decide, you won't need any html knowledge (unless you want to learn) as the platform will take care of your template, content, menu structure, widgets, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you want a blog site install the CMS, Content Management System, Wordpress. There are many templates available which will give you your basic site structure. There are a number of books on Wordpress and you will find wordpress.com helpful. As a site design noob you'll have your work cut out for you.